# raspberry pi, start a script from another PC, Server

Tags: ssh, apache-http-server, script, raspberry-pi, camera

I've got a server (raspberry PI 3  "A") which functions  as a webserver.
Additional I've got a client (raspberry PI 3 "B") with a camera connected.
I've created a script on the client, which creates an image of the camera and then sends it automatically to a volume share of the server.
With a simple `<img>` HTML tag I want to show the image on the website.
Now I have to manually start the script, which triggers the camera.

How can I start a script from the server(webserver) which triggers the script from the client automatically?
I tried to do it with sshpass. Unfortunately that did not work.

How would it work via SSH PASS or what else is a useful way?*

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you could approach this a bit easier:

- Nothing stops you from running a second webserver on `B`, that shows the current image via some CGI mechanism (PHP, bash, ...).
- On `A` you just configure your webserver in aa way, that for the image URL it just proxies the request on to `B`

I consider this much cleaner, as it doesn't rely on some possibly brittle mechanism outside the scope of the webserver.

Comment: Now i understand how to use sshpass and now I can start a script from PC A to start a Script from PC B.